# how to get an async function to restart when encountering errors from an api

Tags: javascript

lets say you have a async function that you want to run continuously. This function retrieves data from an API and Broadcasts responses and every once in a while you receive an error that fetch will fail or there is an issue with the API. Is there a way to have the program restart once it runs into an error.

```
async function main() {
   await fetch_broadcasting_function()

   setInterval(fetch_broadcasting_function, 11000)
}

main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"have the program restart"_? `setInterval()` should continue to try to execute the function every 11s whether it is successful or not

Comment: Catch the error, clearInterval, and execute main again?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the Promise every time you call the function so that

- Execution doesn't stop if it fails the first time (currently, if the first fetch rejects, you never get to the `setInterval` call. Alternatively, you can call `setInterval` first.)
- You don't run into unhandled rejections (during any fetch)

```
const tryFetch = () => fetch_broadcasting_function().catch(() => {});
async function main() {
   await tryFetch(); // you can remove this `await` if desired
   setInterval(tryFetch, 11000)
}

main()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  There are a few things I don't understand. first does "... = () => ..." make tryFetch a function that returns fetch_broadcasting_function()? second ".catch is a method that attaches a callback for only the rejection of the Promise correct? if so what does the parameter syntax mean "(() => {})"

Comment: (1) Not exactly. It returns a `fetch_broadcasting_function` *plus* a `.catch` tacked on so it never rejects. (2) `.catch(() => {})` says: "If the Promise to the left throws, have this whole expression fulfill instead of reject" - thereby avoiding unhandled Promise rejections.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I would call it again, with a try/catch/finally

should be something like this:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await fetch_broadcasting_function();
    setTimeout(main, 11000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('something happened', error);
    main();
  }
}

main()
```

This way, it will only setTimeout if the await succeeds, else it will call main() again...

Comment: I initially tried this but it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure? Are you trying with setInterval or setTimeout?

Comment: I was working with setInterval